# Updating a custom select option on edit.php form when doing a quick edit?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've added a field to the "Quick Edit" feature in WordPress. It works and I can update the database. However, I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to set the initial value of the select menu. It always defaults to "Open" despite using jQuery to try to update the value of the selector to the desired value. Here is the relevant code which I've pieced together from other examples:

```
function quick_edit_javascript() {
    global $current_screen;

    if ( 'grievance' != $current_screen->post_type ) {
        return;
    }
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function value_step( fieldValue ) {
        inlineEditPost.revert();

        // This is the broken part
        jQuery('select[name="step"]').val(fieldValue).change();

        // This gets triggered, so I know code is getting executed:
        alert('hi');
    }
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'quick_edit_javascript' );


/**
 * Pass step value to value_step javascript function
 *
 * @param array $actions
 * @param array $post
 *
 * @return array
 */
function expand_quick_edit_link( $actions, $post ) {
    global $current_screen;

    if ( 'grievance' != $current_screen->post_type ) {
        return $actions;
    }
    $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my_first_plugin_fields', true);
    $data = $meta['step'];

    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js']    = '<a href="#" class="editinline" title="';
    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js']    .= esc_attr( 'Edit this item inline' ) . '"';
    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js']    .= " onclick=\"value_step('{$data}')\" >";
    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js']    .= 'Quick Edit';
    $actions['inline hide-if-no-js']    .= '</a>';

    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'expand_quick_edit_link', 10, 2 );
```

I've tried many different jQuery methods but nothing I do updates the select menu value. Oddly, this works:

```
jQuery('select[name="step"]').hide();
```

So I know the selector works. I've tried setting the select menu with hard-coded values:

```
jQuery('select[name="step"]').val(2).change();
```

and

```
jQuery('select[name="step"]').val('2').change();
```

But that didn't work. I'm not sure what else to try. The HTML for the `select` field looks like this:

```
<div class="inline-edit-col">
    <select name="step"><option value="1">Open</option><option value="2">Closed</option></select>
  </div>
```

Comment: If you log the fieldValue in console using `console.log(fieldValue)` you get the value?

Comment: Immediately after I change the value, I have done:         `alert(jQuery('select[name="step"]').children("option:selected").val());` and it returns the correct value of "2". So it is changing it but the change isn't reflected in the HTML. I think somehow the value gets changed again. I don't know how or where.

Comment: I have tried decreasing the priority on the `add_filter('post_row_actions' ...)` call but that didn't help.

Comment: Just for test put this code in your javascript `jQuery('select[name="step"]').change(function (e) {
            console.log('changed', e.target.value, 'at', e.timeStamp);
        });` that is log in each change in component

Comment: It shows just one change: `changed – "2" – "at" – 1572381354595`

Comment: Well, I posted an answer. No idea why it works the way it does. See below.

Answer (score 0):

There is some voodoo going on under the hood that I'm at a loss to explain. This works (note that the `.inline-edit-col` class was added to the jquery selector but that is not what is making this work):

```
function quick_edit_javascript() {
    global $current_screen;

    if ( 'grievance' != $current_screen->post_type ) {
        return;
    }
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function value_step( fieldValue ) {
        inlineEditPost.revert();
        var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
          alert('check exist');
          if (jQuery('.inline-edit-col select[name="step"]').length) {
                jQuery('.inline-edit-col select[name="step"]').val(2).change();
              clearInterval(checkExist);
          }
        }, 100);
        jQuery('.inline-edit-col select[name="step"]').val('2').change();
        alert('hi');
        alert(jQuery('.inline-edit-col select[name="step"]').children("option:selected").val());
    }
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'quick_edit_javascript' );
```

What I really don't get is that the `alert('hi')` and the alert following that which prints out the field value gets displayed and THEN the `alert('check exist')` alert shows up. Maybe someone more familiar with javascript can help explain what is happening.